# Established translation for "Application crash"?

Tags: перевод, информатика, терминология

What is established translation for "Application crash"? I routinely use simple transliteration `Крэш` or 'падение программы' but that does not sound correct. What is the commonly used translation for that phrase?

Comment: Old vocabularies listed "аварийный останов" and its abbreviation "авост". But this gets out of fashion in 1990s.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It highly depends on the register you're talking/writing at.

- *Аварийное завершение программы* is suitable for a formal register, like a technical manual. It's too wordy to be used in colloquial speech.
- *Падение программы* should be OK in the internal docs targeted at programmers, testers etc. It should probably be OK in speech, even maybe with the users (this depends on their background).
- *Крэш* is very slangy. Sure enough, when speaking to the fellow programmers, this can be more than suitable. However, I'd refrain from using *крэш* in any written docs, manuals, ticket descriptions, or whatever.

Comment: `Падение` can be substituted with `вылет`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you should consider `сбой приложения` or something like `аварийное завершение`?

Comment: May be, but that may mean any application errors, not necessarily leading to the crash (termination)

Comment: @Vladimir, what about "аварийное завершение приложения"?

Comment: @Vladimir application errors would be "ошибки приложения". "Аварийное завершение" is completely ok for crash, while "сбой" is something between.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Helgi explains everything very well, but I would also add to his list `аварийный отказ программы` or simply `отказ программы`. It's not an absolutely equivalent term, but it can be used as a translation.

Comment: I'd say _отказ_ (or _сбой_) means _failure_. It may be non-fatal (failed to open a file). _Crash_, on the other hand, means the application stopped working.

Comment: @Helgi I see your point of view, but in my opinion a failure to open a file is an *action failure*, whereas *program failure* means exactly a total crash, when it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Might be. Still, I'm not sure about this one. For formal usage, it's a bit unspecific (is _отказ_ an action failure or a total failure?). For everyday usage, it might do, but the problem here is I don't remember ever using it or hearing/seeing anyone using it.

Comment: @Helgi Well, Vladimir didn't specify the exact circumstances in which the term is supposed to be used, so I'm just adding one more variant to the list.

Comment: He referred to it as _падение_, and this never means _action failure_.

Comment: @Helgi I don't really understand why you are arguing so persistently. I'm not saying that this term is absolutely equivalent. Yes, it can mean not only application crash. But you can use it in some cases. That's all. I have added a dislaimer in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to offend. I don't think your answer is plain wrong, or I'd downvoted it; I rather wanted to comment on the differences concerning the meaning. For future readers, that is to say.

Comment: @Helgi It's OK, you didn't offend me, I was just trying to understand your point. I think the last edit will clarify the things a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

"Крах приложения" seems like the perfect translation to me - it conveys the meaning, isn't unnecessarily verbose and even sounds similar to the English term.

Comment: Seriously, крах? http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%EA%F0%E0%F5&all=x   Крах suits better for a complete (irreversible?) disaster, but not for an ordinary application crash. Крах sounds too high-flown to my ear.

Comment: @bonomo and what do you think the word [crash](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/crash) means?

Comment: we are not talking about crash out of context of "application crash", are we?

Comment: @bonomo it seems you are taking 'крах' out of context of 'крах приложения'.

Comment: this is exactly what I am talking about, крах in general is an appropriate translation for crash, but speaking of application crashes, крах doesn't seem as appropriate because of its mediocre nature

Comment: @bonomo are you sure "mediocre" is the right word here? You just said it was "high-flown". Frankly, I fail to see why "application" makes "crash" less severe, but "приложения" does not do the same for "крах".

Comment: stay focus my friend, if you recall I said high-flown to the word "крах" as an inappropriate translation of a mediocre thing like application crash

Comment: @bonomo I don't see where this discussion can go if you continue taking one word out of context while putting the other in context.

Comment: oh, i am sorry I forgot of your limitations to follow the line of a conversation, never mind though, you didn't miss much

Answer (score 0):

In oral conversation between programmers is can be:

```
Вылетела с ЖиПиФ'ом.
```

It does not sound like literature Russian, but it is used.

Comment: hm...never heard that :) what is ЖиПиФ?

Comment: @Vladimir ЖиПиФ actually stands for GPF - General Protection Fault error. In modern Windows-family OSes this term is not used anymore.

Comment: @Artemix, thanks good to know :) And yes, you can always say just "вылетела" in informal speech